# Scrapy Pipeline SQL Syntax error

Tags: python, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

I have a spider that grabs URL's from a MySQL DB and uses those URL's as the start_urls to scrape, which in turn grabs any number of new links from the scraped pages. When I set the pipeline to INSERT both the start_url and new scraped url to a new DB or when I set the pipeline to UPDATE the existing DB with the newly scraped URL's using the start_url as the WHERE criteria, I get a SQL syntax error.

When I INSERT just one or the other, I don't get the error.

Here is the spider.py

```
import scrapy
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
from scrapy.http.request import Request

from youtubephase2.items import Youtubephase2Item

class youtubephase2(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'youtubephase2'

    def start_requests(self):
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='uname', passwd='password', db='YouTubeScrape', host='localhost', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute('SELECT resultURL FROM SearchResults;')
        rows = cursor.fetchall()

        for row in rows:
            if row:
                yield Request(row[0], self.parse, meta=dict(start_url=row[0]))
        cursor.close()

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//a[contains(@class, "yt-uix-servicelink")]'):
            item = Youtubephase2Item()
            item['newurl'] = sel.xpath('@href').extract()
            item['start_url'] = response.meta['start_url']
            yield item
```

Here is the pipeline.py which shows all three self.cursor.execute statements

```
import MySQLdb
import MySQLdb.cursors
import hashlib
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from twisted.enterprise import adbapi
from youtubephase2.items import Youtubephase2Item

class MySQLStorePipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='uname', passwd='password', db='YouTubeScrape', host='localhost', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        try:

            #self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE SearchResults SET NewURL = %s WHERE ResultURL = %s VALUES (%s, %s)""",(item['newurl'], item['start_url']))
            #self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE SearchResults SET NewURL = %s WHERE ResultURL = %s""",(item['newurl'], item['start_url']))
            self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO TestResults (NewURL, StartURL) VALUES (%s, %s)""",(item['newurl'], item['start_url']))
            self.conn.commit()


        except MySQLdb.Error, e:
            log.msg("Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1]))

        return item
```

The topmost SQL execute statement returns this error:

```
2017-04-13 18:29:34 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'newurl': [u'http://www.tagband.co.uk/'],
 'start_url': u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqguztfQPho'}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
File "/root/scraping/youtubephase2/youtubephase2/pipelines.py", line 18, in process_item
self.cursor.execute("""UPDATE SearchResults SET AffiliateURL = %s WHERE ResultURL = %s VALUES (%s, %s)""",(item['affiliateurl'], item['start_url']))
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 159, in execute
query = query % db.literal(args)
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

The middle SQL execute statement returns this error:

```
    2017-04-13 18:33:18 [scrapy.log] INFO: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') WHERE ResultURL = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqguztfQPho'' at line 1
2017-04-13 18:33:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqguztfQPho>
{'newurl': [u'http://www.tagband.co.uk/'],
 'start_url': u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqguztfQPho'}
```

The last SQL execute statement returns the same error as the middle even when using an INSERT in to a new database. Seems to add an extra single quote. The last one works when I INSERT only one of the items in to the database.

```
    2017-04-13 18:36:40 [scrapy.log] INFO: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqguztfQPho')' at line 1
2017-04-13 18:36:40 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqguztfQPho>
{'newurl': [u'http://www.tagband.co.uk/'],
'start_url': u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UqguztfQPho'}
```

Sorry about the long post. Trying to be thorough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. The issue has to do with the fact that I was passing a list to the MySQL execute pipeline.

I created a pipeline that converts the list to a string with "".join(item['newurl']) and returns the item prior to hitting the MySQL Pipeline.

Maybe there is a better way to change the item['newurl'] = sel.xpath('@href').extract() line in the spider.py to extract the first item in the list or convert it to text but a pipeline worked for me.

Comment: yes, there is a more idiomatic way to select the 1st element: `item['newurl'] = sel.xpath('@href').extract_first()`

Comment: Well I feel stupid. I have used that before, not realizing it would be the easy solution in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Don't feel stupid. If you didn't find this information, it probably means that the selectors documentation can be improved (assuming that you've read https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html)